# Steps to follow regarding crashlytics

Tags: ios, crashlytics

I am new to crashlytics. I entered my email and clicked on Try crashlytics. It redirected to another page showing You're on The list etc.Under General Info i entered my Name and my Company and clicked on "Put me on top".Then what are the steps should i follow to use crashlytics in my ios application. I am not getting what are the further steps should i follow?

Comment: You need to wait for them to send you an email telling you you're in. It should not take much time (I think less than a day)

Comment: @Moxy I registerd 2 days back itself. I also commented on crashlytics twitter account regarding this.

Comment: Week end! you should wait some more ;)

Answer (score 3):

When I registered for their service i was facing the same question, without an imminent answer on hand. 
So I wrote them on Twitter and got a response in about an hour, which stated that they will process my request imidiately.

And they did. They created a batch just for me (the whole process from registration till the end implementation on my side was done in less than one day).

thumbs up for their customer service! I have never seen better :)

Answer (score 1):

with monday being a holiday you might have an extra day to wait. have a little bit of patience, it is totally worth the wait. I migrated from BugSense to HockeyApp to Crashlytics. The fact that they're free is insane. I've got a couple feature requests in to them and they quickly got back to me and said that they have them on the roadmap. They're a cool group of people and were just scooped up by Twitter.

Enjoy it.

Comment: How long i should wait just for registration?

Comment: i had mine within a few days. there isnt really anything for you to do at this point except wait for another email from them.